# WPF RibbonButton

Tags: wpf, ribbon

How can I programatically set the text on a RibbonButton? Right now I have the code below, but the button does not display 'Browse'. Any suggestions?

```
RibbonButton btn = new RibbonButton();
btn.Name = "btnBrowse";
btn.Content = "Browse";
btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left;
btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

RibbonButtons from the RibbonControlsLibrary behave differently than standard WPF buttons and need a command to display text. The command is where you also assign the images and other items such as tool tips.

```
var cmd = new RibbonCommand();
cmd.LabelTitle = "Browse";
cmd.CanExecute += ( sender, args ) => args.CanExecute = true;
cmd.Executed +=new ExecutedRoutedEventHandler(cmd_Executed);

var btn = new RibbonButton();
btn.Command = cmd;

MyRibbonGroup.Controls.Add( btn );
```

You must assign true to CanExecute, otherwise will the command/button will always be disabled. The CanExecute method can have your business logic disable or enable the command/button as well.

Comment: You are right, if you have the button inside a RibbonGroup. But if you have it in a RibbonControlGroup (as I had it), it doesn't work

Comment: RibbonCommand is removed from WPF Ribbon. Now, how do we set label etc of a button?

Comment: @Mert - It's been awhile since I've looked at the MS WPF Ribbon. You may want to post your question as a new question as reference this answer as possibly being no longer valid with the new release (I can't verify this, though).

Answer (score 1):

WPF Buttons are containers like just about everything else in WPF. Create a TextBlock and set it as the Content of your button:

```
RibbonButton btn = new RibbonButton(); 
btn.Name = "btnBrowse"; 
TextBlock btnText = new TextBlock();
btnText.Text = "Browse";
btn.Content = btnText; 
btn.HorizontalAlignment = System.Windows.HorizontalAlignment.Left; 
btn.Click += new RoutedEventHandler(btn_Click);
```

That said, I hightly suggest you consider building your UI in XAML. If the text will change during runtime, databind the text of the button.

Comment: RibbonButtons from the RibbonControlsLibrary behave differently than standard WPF buttons. See my answer.

Comment: Unfortunately, it doesn't work.. they seem to have a different behavior than normal buttons

Comment: @Metro Smurf: interesting, thanks for the comment and the other answer; I was unaware of that. I'm going to keep mine around so anyone swinging by can see the difference.

Comment: Hopefully the Ribbon team will release an update soon that will resolve many of these differences, as well as bug-fixes.